# Why does .NET keeps selecting "SslProtocolsv= Default" for my app in this specific environment

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, windows-server-2016, .net-4.8

I have a .NET Framework 4.8 application that I release and run of 3 environments.
This app calls a REST API that supports Tls1.2.
In one of the three environments, the app triggers the following error:
**"connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"**

I suspect a TLS negotiation issue, so I enabled network tracing as
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing

Here is what I observe:

- My local machine (Windows 11): the call to the API is successful. The
  network tracing shows **"SslProtocols=None"**
- Test environment A (Windows    server 1016): the call to the API is
  successful. The network tracing    shows **"SslProtocols=tls, tls11,
  tls12, tls13"**
- Test environment B    (Windows server 1016): the call to the API **fails**. The network    tracing shows **"SslProtocols=Default"**

The Microsoft documentation on the SslProtocols enum shows that "none" is acceptable as it means the protocol will be selected by the OS.
But "default" seems to be a pretty bad value because it forces tls1.0 and ssl3 which are obsolete protocols.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols?view=net-7.0

My question is:
why does the NET Framework decide to use **SslProtocols=Default** in Test Environment B? It literally breaks my app.

I have tried forcing tls1.2 in my code with either ONE of the following additions before I call the REST API and it works. But it's a bad practice as it prevents forward compatibility with tls1.3

```
ServiceManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocoltype.Tls12;
```

Or:

```
HttpClientHandler = new HttpclientHandler { System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12};
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler)
```

Comment: What are the registry values of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SchUseStrongCrypto` on both A and B systems?

Comment: @DavidG On Test Environment A it is set to 1 and my app works. On Test Environment B, the key does not exist and my app does not work.

Comment: This could be the difference then. If you set that value on B (and restart) does that make it work?